# MSYS2 gcc undefined reference _assert, what library am i missing?

Tags: gcc, linker, mingw, msys2, raylib

Im trying to link with a game  library that has already been compiled using mingw, called Raylib.  However; whenever I use MSYS's gcc 10.2 it gives me the following undefined reference error:

```
gcc main.c -Iraylib-3.7.0_win64_mingw-w64/include -Lraylib-3.7.0_win64_mingw-w64/lib -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: raylib-3.7.0_win64_mingw-w64/lib/libraylib.a(core.o):core.c:(.text+0x1f6e): undefined reference to '_assert'
```

It seems that I maybe missing a library? This is just one of many similar errors. The majority of these undefined references are for assert like the one listed above. Some deal with GLFW and other libraries. Has anyone experienced something like this on MSYS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to be directly in MSYS2 mingw64 environment (cmd prompt). I was using the regular MSYS2 MSYS environment.

Comment: The environment you use affects what compiler is in the PATH. In MSYS2 MSYS you get not regular MinGW, but Cygwin, which you almost never want.